# Custom Icon Font in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to use an custom icon font for my application, so ill added the font "simple-line-icons.ttf" into my info.plist - and now i can choose it from interface builder.

When ill set the text from a label to the unicode text, like:

```
    dateIconLabel.text = "\u{e01c}"
```

It shows me an icon, but not the icon from the icon set as expected.

Its an colored icon, and i dont use any colered icon sets here.

The font is definitive correct, and the unicode should work too (copied from the original css file).

Something strange is, that when ill print out all fonts for my application, the icon font is not there (but its in my list in IB).

```
    print(UIFont.familyNames())
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can try 'dateIconLabel.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Your-font-name", size: 17)'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the icon font is added to the correct target. When I added the font to my app it was not added to any target. So the icon font was not installed in the app and the system was using a default font.

You could still select the font in IB because you probably installed the font on your mac.

Comment: Oh youre right, ill added the font with in the Build Phases in Copy Bundle Ressource and now it works fine! Its a little bit strange when you see other icons from another (System?) font.

Answer (score 0):

Add the font to the info.plist

use:UIAppFonts (Raw Value) or "Fonts Provided by application" as the key,
and the font name example Icon-Font.ttf

Validate that the font file name and font name correspond by opening ttf in font book